# Twitter OAuth authen token key: Unknown character returned

Tags: windows-phone-7, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm building the Twitter Client in Windows Phone, using Hammock Library DLL
When I try to get the twitter access token key after I entered my username and password,
I got the return access token key in a very strange characters form.

This is what I got from the Twitter API:

"�\b\0\0\0\0\0�D�K�0@��03�߀����#�\0���b��k���Hpϝ�E�V͜\noo-[���#�༑,W]��eDz�#�p���,�\t��?k�?o%%@�w��¬���)�Q��\a�^a�>9TNi�8Y��H\n�x��5�%��z�(!�\0\0��\0_��Ԡ\0\0\0"

So after that it will be unsuccessful and won't redirect me back to my application.

Any idea of what happens?

Thank you.

[image: Strange fonts]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OAuth token might be encoded in GZip.

Here is the code snippet to handle that case:

```
if (webResponse.Headers["Content-Encoding"] == "gzip")
{
  stream = new GZipInputStream(stream);
}
```